# Lower the rep required to chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-users, chat

I suggest we lower the rep required to chat to 1.

This way we can help new users understand the site instead of having them "crash and burn" on main with a invalid or non-golfed submission or an awful challenge.

Also, if a user *does* "crash and burn", than we can explain what they did wrong to them in chat.

Comment: The chat privilege is network-wide; I doubt PPCG users will get a different threshold.

Comment: Because it affects only *our* meta site. Once you get 20 rep on PPCG, you can chat in *any* SE chat room.

Comment: Technically? Sure. But I venture to guess that making the required changes would require a non-trivial amount of work. The meta privilege was adjustable anyway, so someone just had to flick a switch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this: A spammer goes onto Stack Exchange Chat, then creates an account, and then is promptly allowed to post messages immediately.

This is an obvious flaw. If something requires rep, it means that you have to have demonstrated sufficient helpfulness (or at least decency) before being allowed to do that.